# Problems configuring the Web Content Viewer (286)

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I'm having problems while attempting to configure the Web Content Viewer (286) portlet.

When I attempt to configure this portlet and try to select a content item or component I get 
a pop-up that contains the same page as the parent. See the following screenshot:

[image]

The same issue has been identified in two separate portal:

- A portal running WebSphere Portal 7 with no fixes or upgrades
- A portal running WebSphere Portal 7.0.0.1 that has the latest combined cumulative fix (7.0.0.1-WP-WCM-Combined-CFPM49013-CF009)

Now I checked the fixes for Lotus Web Content Management, but the latest fix is  the cumulative fix 18 (PM434406).
I check the system out and the combined WCM fix in my portal is the cumulative fix 23 (PM49882); which superseeds the one found at fix central.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to go ahead and create a PMR for this issue. Our problem was that for some reason when we created a virtual portal the **Web Content Management** page was not created under the **hidden pages** label in the Virtual Portal. However this page existed in the base portal.

There were two possible fixes for this issue:

- Export the page at the base portal and import it at the virtual portal, or
- Run the update-wcm ConfigEngine task right after creating the Virtual Portal.

Good luck to everyone.